# How to get a global object which has been set in a Java Servlet Context

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets

I am working on a Tomcat application which populates a HashMap on startup. I set it in the ServletContext using ServletContext.setAttribute. However, I have some non Java EE classes also in this application (basically my webservice calls call those methods). I want to access this HashMap in those Methods. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Either send them the hashMap and let them do whatever you want to do, or even better: expose a service that handles the map.

Comment: Is there a way I can do it without setting it in the Context? Is there a way I can keep a handle to an Object through out the lifetime of my Tomcat application?

Comment: yes, that's what I said: create a service (could be a singleton) that handles that map. You can access the service from anywhere and that service will "hide" the hashmap and expose only its functionalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your web service should have access to HTTP Request and Response where you can get ServletContext. When web services call these non J2EE methods, you can pass the map as a argument parameter.

Comment: I wish I could but the code is managed by spring and generated by CXF and didnot want to disturb that.

Comment: You can add a ServletContextListener in the web xml file.
In this listener, you can load your items into a static HashMap
where later your POJO will have access to them.

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Fetch the HashMap in your web service class and pass on the same as method argument to your non Java EE classes.

Comment: Is there a way I can do it without setting it in the Context? Is there a way I can keep a handle to an Object through out the lifetime of my Tomcat application?

Comment: ServletContext is used for saving things that you want to use across different application. ServletConfig is used to store things that you want to access only in a particular application.

Comment: Is  there a reason you don't want to use ServletContext?

Comment: I want to use ServletContext but was unable to retrieve ServletContext as it is a non Tomcat Class. However now I am using ServletContextAware to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your map available to all classes of your application:

- ***Using a Singleton***

  See [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java)
- ***Using Tomcat global JNDI tree*** (not recommended, but you can do it).

  See [How do you save name-value pairs in Tomcat environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972160/how-do-you-save-name-value-pairs-in-tomcat-environment) and [Apache Tomcat 7 - JNDI Resources HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html)

Comment: I thought of singleton but wanted a more efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the suggestions. However what I was trying to achieve was achieved by the following example:

http://www.xinotes.net/notes/note/1772/

It gave me a method to retrieve the context in non-Tomcat handled classes.